# Unable to exit the YouTube player and return to the app on an iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, youtube, embed

I'm embedding one or more youtube video urls in a UIWebView using  tags as commonly found in samples.

Clicking the thumbnail launches the YouTube video player. When tested on an iPod Touch, the video opens in landscape format, and clicking Done closes the Player and returns to the app as desired.

When testing on an iPad, the Player opens in portrait orientation, slightly truncating some of the UI controls, though, the status bar does flip over to the landscape position. The video plays in portrait orientation. Clicking done will stop the video, but not dismiss the player, but my app is still running (I can see the debugger is still running). If I close the Player, it kills my app.

Strangely, if I get an error while loading the video, the player will pop up a message, and after closing the message, the player closes and returns me to the app.

I'm compiling with iOS4 as the base SDK and OS3.0 as the target, so, I'm running an iPhone app on the iPad, but I'd like it to behave the same way it does on the Touch.

What can I expect the app to do on iPhones with and without iOS4?

Thanks in advance, Mike

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. Code returns to app on iPhone4 no problem. Running it on iPad plays it in webview (rather than launching Youtube player). But that's not a bigie as you can maximise it and plays full screen. But pressing DONE return to springboard. App is still shown as being in the memory but activating behaves like it was restarted.

Comment: That's good to know about iPhone4. Have you tried on iPad 4.2? I was hoping that with task switching I'd be able to get back to the same view I was on without restarting the app, but I haven't had a chance to install the 4.2 SDK yet.